# An unclear error in SQL DB2 (DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null)

Tags: sql, database, exception, error-handling, db2

I am using SQL on DB2 and I am receiving this error

```
Exception message:
A SQL exception was caught. The error was: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.19.49.
```

I understand the nature of the error, but I don't understand the SQLERRMC parameter. The official documentation doesn't helps so much. Can you explain what this mean?

Comment: And that error happened when you did... what?

Comment: Insert into Database

Comment: The documentation seems very clear for SQL0302N (the value a a host variable ...is out of range for its corresponding use -- i.e. the application code has a mistake ) , which bit do you fail to understand? Edit your question to show your Db2-platform (z/os, i-series,  linux/unix/windows)  and your Db2-version.  For insert, one (or mode) column value is too long, or too short, or too high or too low etc.

Comment: What's the SQL statement that is failing?

Comment: It's an inner insertion of another program I cannot report it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, in my case, was that the field was too long for the destination.
Thus, probably the field SQLERRMC had no reason to exist.

This is the best answer I've found for now, still unsure regarding the general meaning of the field.